# Flattening/extracting from folders with duplicate file names in correct order, is this possible in finder/terminal/any app?

Tags: macos, finder, filesystem, folders, file

I know the trick of command F and searching within multiple folders to copy paste and get out different named files from folders quickly, but I often come across horrible folders like this with the same file names inside:

[image]

If I try that trick, it will warn me about overwriting, if I do it by track pad dragging, it's very slow, is there any way I can extract them in the correct order and add a name, I searched commercial products and found nothing that would do it.

Comment: I am not clear what you are trying to do. Is it move all files to one folder but if there are duplicate names rename one of them? If so what is the rule for renaming?

Comment: thanks for reply, move all the identically named files inside the folders to the outside of their folders, into the main folder, and rename them all by adding a character because their will be dupes, but based on the chronological order of the folders they came from, so they remain in order, up to down, I think it's possible with scripting but might not be easy, windows just adds a number in the same situation but mac will not allow dupes, very different filesystem obviously.